# Pose proof in Coq

Tags: coq

I’m trying to prove a theorem in Coq. My current context is:

```
1 subgoal
s, x : Entity
Pssx : Ps s x
Fxs : F x s
IPssx : F x s /\ Ps s x
t : Entity
Ctss : C t s s
Pstx : Ps t x
Fxt : F x t
______________________________________(1/1)
C s s s
```

`F`, `Ps` and `C` are relations of the theory. I’ve also Axiom 4:

```
Axiom A4 : forall x s t,
  Ps s x /\ F x s /\ Ps t x /\ F x t -> s = t.
```

What I want to do, is to use A4 in the proof, as it will help me to say that s and t are equals. So I’ve tested: `pose proof (A4 x s t).` A new hypothesis is added : `H : Ps s x /\ F x s /\ Ps t x /\ F x t -> s = t`. I know I can destruct the hypothesis H, prove the premisses and use the conclusion. But I also know that I can give the premisses directly in the `pose proof` command. I want to do something like `pose proof (A4 x s t Premisses).` But I don’t know what to put instead of `Premisses`.

I tried several solutions:

- composing the hypothesis with /, such as `pose proof (A4 x s t (Pssx /\ Fxs /\ Pstx /\ Fxt)).` but I got the error `The term "Pssx" has type "Ps s x" while it is expected to have type "Ps s x /\ F x s /\ Ps t x /\ F x t".`
- using the `assert` command and `pose proof (A4 x s t H1).`:

  - `assert (H1 := (Ps s x) /\ (F x s) /\ (Ps t x) /\ (F x t)).` but I got `The term "H1" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type "Ps s x /\ F x s /\ Ps t x /\ F x t".`
  - `assert (H1 := (Pssx) /\ (Fxs) /\ (Pstx) /\ (Fxt)).` but I got `The term "Pssx" has type "Ps s x" while it is expected to have type "Prop".`

So my question is the following: what should I put instead of `Premisses` for my code to work? Is there a command to create new hypothesis based on other ones? I know how to destruct an hypothesis into two smaller hypothesis, but I don't know how to compose hypothesis to create bigger ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard in Coq would be to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) your `A4` so that instead of receiving one large conjunction as a premise, it receives several different premises:

```
Axiom A4' : forall x s t,
  Ps s x -> F x s -> Ps t x -> F x t -> s = t.
```

Then you can do:

```
pose proof (A4' x s t Pssx Fxs Pstx Fxt).
```

If you absolutely need `A4` with the conjunctions, you can use `conj` (which you can find with `Print "_ /\ _"`):

```
pose proof (A4 x s t (conj Pssx (conj Fxs (conj Pstx Fxt)))).
```